# php : Error 500 : premature end of script headers when executing loop in a script

Tags: php, runtime-error

I'm running in a very disturbing  "error 500"  when running a gradient descent algorithm in a php script on a ~50x25 matrices.

If I set the number of iterations of the gradient to a very small number (<3), it works fine. But if I increase it to 4 iterations , it starts throwing an error 500 (premature end of script headers) almost all the time. If the number of iterations is greater then 4, then it never works. I've checked the script memory consumption and it's lesser than 3MB so it should be fine on this side.

The script is hosted on a shared server (OVH), so it may use too much CPU for the server or executing too many requests, but the problem is that I don't have any idea of how to know where the problem comes from. I've read many posts (here or on other forums) about this type of errors, and about the number of requests allowed for a script that could be the cause of it, so I added `ini_set('pm.max_requests', 0);` at the beginning of the script but nothing changed.

My PHP knowledge is very limited, so I am ready to hear any piece of advice youu have to get rid of this error ! :D

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ensure you log errors with your webserver as well as with your php. Check the error log of your webserver for your 500 error. Also check the php error log. That should give you more information to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: The only log error I have seen is the log from my web hosting service (OVH) at logs.ovh.net . I think it's the only log I have access to and what I see there is just : _[Mon Oct 15 11:09:10 2012] [error] [client IP] [host www.mysite.com] Premature end of script headers: index.php_ I don't think I can have more information :/